# Using setinterval with updating a state in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

The following code demonstrates a react functional component that has a single state variable named `time`.  It has a button `click to start` which fires a function named `updateTimer`. This meant to move the timer from `0` to `1` to `2` to `3` and so on.

```
function timer() {

       const [time, updateTime] = useState(0);
       
       function updateTimer() {
           setInterval(() => {
              updateTime(time + 1)
           },1000)
      }
}

return (
      <>
        <span>{time} seconds</span>
        <button onClick={updateTimer}>Click To Start</button>
      </>
)
```

But what happens is that the timer stops after `1`. Apparently, the value of `time` does not get updated. Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1):

To update the state depending on the previous state use:

```js
updateTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `updateTime` updates the value of `time` in the next render of the component, the `time` known to the `setInterval` callback is not updated and remained the initial value `0`, and resets to `1` at every interval.

In a [`useEffect`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect) run the setter `updateTime` based on [previous value](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) to correct the counting, also cleanup and recreate the interval as needed when the counting starts or stops.

For a basic example, the following `useEffect` starts an interval when `updating` is set `true` by the `button`. The `return` runs when
`updating` changes or when the component unmounted for cleaning up the interval, before a new one can be recreated.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!updating) return;
    const count = setInterval(() => {
      updateTime((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(count);
    };
  }, [updating]);
```

`updating` is added to the dependencies array so that `useEffect` listens to the changes of this state, and creates a new interval if it is `true`.

The setter `updateTime` does not change and it sets `time` based on the previous value internally, so `updateTime` and `time` do not need to be included in the dependencies array.

Example in full snippet:

```js
const { useState, useEffect, Fragment } = React;

function Timer() {
  const [time, updateTime] = useState(0);
  const [updating, setUpdating] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!updating) return;
    const count = setInterval(() => {
      updateTime((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(count);
    };
  }, [updating]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <p>{time} seconds</p>
      <button onClick={() => setUpdating((prev) => !prev)}>{`Click To ${
        updating ? "Stop" : "Start"
      }`}</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Timer />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
.App {
  font-size: x-large;
}

button {
  padding: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you explain the code inside `useEffect`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Thanks for the reply, tried my best to update with some details., but for further information do reference the React document regarding [state updating](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) and [useEffect](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect).